# Looking for an Alternative to call a Target with Parameters(=Properties)

Tags: msbuild

I've created a target that calls different sub targets to fulfil a certain job, e.g copying files and running actions on them.

Now I want to call this target multiple times with different parameters (=properties)

The current command line looks like this:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe d:\Sync\sync.msbuild.xml /p:source="D:\temp" /p:destination="P:\d\temp"
```

Now this command line gets called very often with different properties for source and destination.

I would like to create a msbuild "project" file which imports the build targets from sync.msbuild.xml (this part is trivial) and define one large target that invokes the imported default or any other target.

I've explored some options and my conclusion is that I would like to avoid to use `CallTarget` as I would need to create properties with `CreateProperty` resulting in being too verbose (which I am trying to avoid with the "project" build file.

Another option via Exec also requires too much redundancy, I would need to store the path to MSBuild and spawn "sub" msbuild instances, which is also not ideal. This equals to having a batch file executing msbuild.

Is there a proper solution to this? Are there `Task`s that can invoke a target. (Not by creating a code fragment task which calls Process.Start)

And I would like to not introduce batch, python or anything else to the toolchain.

Comment: Can you give an example in msbuild or pseudocode of what you want this large target to do exactly? I read your qeustion a couple of times and I still am not sure.. Probably you just can use the MsBuild task and invoke it sort of recursively on the project file itself, but again, I'm not sure if that is what you're after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to recursively call MSBuild. Read an answer like [How do you recursively call tasks in MSBuild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556449/how-do-you-recursively-call-tasks-in-msbuild) and you will see the light.

If you need to more complex iterations, I blogged about "nested looping" [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/giuliov/gotcha-msbuild-nested-loops-double-batching).

Comment: beat me to it by 5 seconds

Comment: @giulio-van Looks like that blog is no longer online. Any chance there's still a record of that somewhere? I tried WayBackMachine but it hadn't archived it.

Comment: They moved the content to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/giuliov/gotcha-msbuild-nested-loops-double-batching . I fixed the link but formatting isn't great. Hope it works for you.